# App widget button to trigger onUpdate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override   
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.example_appwidget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Fragment_testActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
        // widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
}

}
```

Why doesn't the button1 trigger `onUpdate` (nor `onReceive`) when the widget is added to the homescreen and button1 is clicked? Adding/removing the widget triggers those events, but not clicking the button.

[Manifest](https://gist.github.com/2133595), [widget declaration](https://gist.github.com/2133611), [widget layout declaration](https://gist.github.com/2133628)

Comment: First thing I see: `new Intent(context, Fragment_testActivity.class);
` - you specify an activity as the receiving component. The activity has nothing to do with the update process. Try to set ExampleAppWidgetProvider as the component of the intent or don't specify a component at all (`new Intent()`).

Comment: SYLARRR, see this one [handle button click on widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633100/how-to-handle-button-click-on-widget/9633400#9633400) and you must register an Intent Action for update on button click

Comment: @alextsec thank you, `new Intent(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);` fixed the problem. Add this as an answer to this question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I see:

```
new Intent(context, Fragment_testActivity.class);
```

You specify an activity as the receiving component. The activity has nothing to do with the update process. Try to set ExampleAppWidgetProvider as the component of the intent or don't specify a component at all (e.g. by using `new Intent()`).